# PROMQl query to check if a service is running for a duration

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am new to Prometheus. I am able to collect metrics from different exporters. I have a metric like
`test_foo_info{test_id="6500115",test_name="API Test",test_type="HTTP",test_uptime_percent="100",test_url="xyz/health"} 1.0`

How should I write the query or figure out in the Grafana dashboard via promql query to see if any `test_name` in the above case is "API test" does not have `test_uptime_percent` equal to 100 % for 2 minutes, I should trigger an alert.

I have multiple metrics like the above for different test_name and I have to set up alerts for all of them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It isn't recommended storing percent values in labels, since every unique label value results in additional time series . This may lead to [high cardinality issues](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-cardinality).

Comment: Thank you @valyala !! You are right and I approached the problem by creating a panel and just having the query test_foo_info{$test_name} < 1